# Variable Buffer in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am new to this Post. Kindly let me know if I make any mistake the way I am asking question.

My question can be clearly understandable when one can go through these links where I have explained what I am looking for.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nhmxqgveytl0ba/Comb%20FIR%20Filter%20Explanation.jpg

```
                 (And)
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5nhmxqgveytl0ba/Comb%20FIR%20Filter%20Explanation.jpg

The major point will be "How Can I create such a 'Variable FIFO buffer' whcih depends on input period & Filter sampling frequency 'Fs'?

If any one out there has any Idea or soultion for such a problem, Then I will be very glad to know and it will help me a lot in my project here.

Sincerely
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't fully understand what it is you're looking for here but I think you already have all the information that you need.

```
Fs = 1000; %% or whatever your sampling rate is to begin with.
Order = 3; %% Or whatever order you decide to work with.
Buffer_length = (Order/2)*Fs; % this will be the amount of data in each buffer
```

If you're looking for someone to give you anything more than this you're going to have to provide additional information and show what you're tried to do so far.

Comment: But buffer_length = (Input Period/2)*Fs  i.e. if all the samples from a one period is considered  then buffer_length=(1/2)*Fs. I really don't know how I can put it at it's best though. What kind of additional information may require, if I may ask you please? I will be glad to provide it here.  As far as I have implemented is buffer as this but a fixed one.                                                                                          

    buff_Size = 10;
    Buff = size(1,buff_Size);
    for new_val = 1:10
        cirBuff = [new_val Buff(1:end-1)]
    end